# Backup /var/lib/docker without the images?

Tags: docker

I want to make a backup of all my containers and volumes, so the easiest way would be to copy `/var/lib/docker` to another location.

However this directory also includes all the images, and I don't want to include them since they all can easily be re-downloaded from public sources.

So how can I copy this directory while excluding the images?

Comment: Virtually every copy and backup tool provides an exclude parameter.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Ofcourse, I just want to know which directory or files to exclude. It's very hard to differentiate between volumes and images because they reside in the same directory (overlay2) and have cryptic names.

Comment: @Maestro: Aren't volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`?

Comment: @EricDuminil Volumes are data stored by the containers. I need to preserve that data, I just dont want the container image files.

Comment: Yes. But AFAICT, images are stored in `overlay2`, volumes are stored in `volumes`. They don't reside in the same directory.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes but any changes to the images made during the runtime of the container are also stored in `overlay2`, so I cant just exclude that whole folder.

Comment: From what I understood, I think you should not care about data present only in containers. Important static data should be defined in Dockerfile/docker-compose. Important data should be saved to volumes (named or bound). It shouldn't be a problem to delete images and containers, and recreate them when needed.